# How can I optimize my query/environment to improve MySQL sorting on a large data set?

Tags: mysql

Here's a sample MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item.ID, item.CREATED_AT
FROM  `item` ,  `image` 
WHERE item.COLLECTION_ID =9
AND item.REJECTED IS NULL 
AND image.ITEM_ID = item.ID
ORDER BY item.CREATED_AT DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

And here's the explain results:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  item    ref PRIMARY,item_FI_1,rejected  item_FI_1   4   const   313775  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  image   ref item_id item_id 3   dbname.item.id  1   Using where; Using index; Distinct
```

Sorry, but I can only show the phpMyAdmin explain output at the moment.

Here's the CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `collection_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `variant_id` int(11) default NULL,
 `duplicate_id` int(11) default NULL,
 `rejected` tinyint(4) default NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `remote_key` int(11) default NULL,
 `created_at` datetime default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 KEY `item_FI_1` (`collection_id`),
 KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
 KEY `rejected` (`rejected`),
 KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `item_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`) REFERENCES `collection` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=691849 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here's my variables:

```
auto increment increment    1
auto increment offset   1
automatic sp privileges ON
back log    50
basedir /
binlog cache size   32,768
bulk insert buffer size 8,388,608
character set client    utf8
(Global value)  latin1
character set connection    utf8
(Global value)  latin1
character set database  latin1
character set filesystem    binary
character set results   utf8
(Global value)  latin1
character set server    latin1
character set system    utf8
character sets dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation connection    utf8_general_ci
(Global value)  latin1_swedish_ci
collation database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion type 0
concurrent insert   1
connect timeout 10
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date format %Y-%m-%d
datetime format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default week format 0
delay key write ON
delayed insert limit    100
delayed insert timeout  300
delayed queue size  1,000
div precision increment 4
keep files on create    OFF
engine condition pushdown   OFF
expire logs days    0
flush   OFF
flush time  0
ft boolean syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft max word len 84
ft min word len 4
ft query expansion limit    20
ft stopword file    (built-in)
group concat max len    1,024
have archive    YES
have bdb    NO
have blackhole engine   YES
have compress   YES
have community features NO
have profiling  NO
have crypt  YES
have csv    YES
have dynamic loading    YES
have example engine YES
have federated engine   YES
have geometry   YES
have innodb YES
have isam   NO
have merge engine   YES
have ndbcluster NO
have openssl    NO
have ssl    NO
have query cache    YES
have raid   NO
have rtree keys YES
have symlink    YES
hostname    server1.gocodev.com
init connect    
init file   
init slave  
innodb additional mem pool size 1,048,576
innodb autoextend increment 8
innodb buffer pool awe mem mb   0
innodb buffer pool size 268,435,456
innodb checksums    ON
innodb commit concurrency   0
innodb concurrency tickets  500
innodb data file path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb data home dir    
innodb adaptive hash index  ON
innodb doublewrite  ON
innodb fast shutdown    1
innodb file io threads  4
innodb file per table   OFF
innodb flush log at trx commit  1
innodb flush method 
innodb force recovery   0
innodb lock wait timeout    50
innodb locks unsafe for binlog  OFF
innodb log arch dir 
innodb log archive  OFF
innodb log buffer size  1,048,576
innodb log file size    5,242,880
innodb log files in group   2
innodb log group home dir   ./
innodb max dirty pages pct  90
innodb max purge lag    0
innodb mirrored log groups  1
innodb open files   300
innodb rollback on timeout  OFF
innodb support xa   ON
innodb sync spin loops  20
innodb table locks  ON
innodb thread concurrency   8
innodb thread sleep delay   10,000
innodb use legacy cardinality algorithm ON
interactive timeout 28,800
join buffer size    131,072
key buffer size 8,384,512
key cache age threshold 300
key cache block size    1,024
key cache division limit    100
language    /usr/share/mysql/english/
large files support ON
large page size 0
large pages OFF
lc time names   en_US
license GPL
local infile    ON
locked in memory    OFF
log OFF
log bin OFF
log bin trust function creators OFF
log error   
log queries not using indexes   OFF
log slave updates   OFF
log slow queries    OFF
log warnings    1
long query time 10
low priority updates    OFF
lower case file system  OFF
lower case table names  0
max allowed packet  1,048,576
max binlog cache size   4,294,963,200
max binlog size 1,073,741,824
max connect errors  10
max connections 500
max delayed threads 20
max error count 64
max heap table size 134,217,728
max insert delayed threads  20
max join size   18446744073709551615
max length for sort data    1,024
max prepared stmt count 16,382
max relay log size  0
max seeks for key   4,294,967,295
max sort length 1,024
max sp recursion depth  0
max tmp tables  32
max user connections    0
max write lock count    4,294,967,295
multi range count   256
myisam data pointer size    6
myisam max sort file size   2,146,435,072
myisam mmap size    4,294,967,295
myisam recover options  OFF
myisam repair threads   1
myisam sort buffer size 8,388,608
myisam stats method nulls_unequal
net buffer length   16,384
net read timeout    30
net retry count 10
net write timeout   60
new OFF
old passwords   OFF
open files limit    2,500
optimizer prune level   1
optimizer search depth  62
pid file    /var/lib/mysql/server1.gocodev.com.pid
plugin dir  
port    3,306
preload buffer size 32,768
protocol version    10
query alloc block size  8,192
query cache limit   1,048,576
query cache min res unit    4,096
query cache size    0
query cache type    ON
query cache wlock invalidate    OFF
query prealloc size 8,192
range alloc block size  4,096
read buffer size    131,072
read only   OFF
read rnd buffer size    262,144
relay log   
relay log index 
relay log info file relay-log.info
relay log purge ON
relay log space limit   0
rpl recovery rank   0
secure auth OFF
secure file priv    
server id   0
skip external locking   ON
skip networking OFF
skip show database  OFF
slave compressed protocol   OFF
slave load tmpdir   /tmp/
slave net timeout   3,600
slave skip errors   OFF
slave transaction retries   10
slow launch time    2
socket  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sort buffer size    6,291,456
sql big selects ON
sql mode    
sql notes   ON
sql warnings    OFF
ssl ca  
ssl capath  
ssl cert    
ssl cipher  
ssl key 
storage engine  InnoDB
sync binlog 0
sync frm    ON
system time zone    GMT
table cache 64
table lock wait timeout 50
table type  InnoDB
thread cache size   0
thread stack    196,608
time format %H:%i:%s
time zone   SYSTEM
timed mutexes   OFF
tmp table size  134,217,728
tmpdir  /tmp/
transaction alloc block size    8,192
transaction prealloc size   4,096
tx isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
updatable views with limit  YES
version 5.0.92-community
version comment MySQL Community Edition (GPL)
version compile machine i686
version compile os  pc-linux-gnu
wait timeout    28,800
```

Any thoughts on how I can improve performance on this?  My queries are averaging around 3 seconds on the above (pertaining to about 600,000 query matches).  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post  table structure and indexes for `item`?

Comment: Just posted some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

create a sorted view of the table first, and then query from the view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_sorted_items AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
 item.ID, 
 item.CREATED_AT 
FROM  
 `item` ,  
 `image`  
WHERE 
 item.COLLECTION_ID =9 
AND item.REJECTED IS NULL  
AND image.ITEM_ID = item.ID 
ORDER BY item.CREATED_AT DESC  LIMIT 0, 30
```

You also might want to explicitely join the tables..

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 item.id,
 item.created_at
FROM
 item LEFT JOIN image ON item.item_id = image.item_id
WHERE
 item.collection_id = 9
and item.rejected is null
ORDER BY
 item.created_at DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

The first item (creating a view) will DEFFINATELY help your performance... the 2nd is just good practice, and it may or may not ultimately help.  You should probably also FK the item id on the image table.

Comment: Why do you think using a view will help performance? Also, if you are going to rewrite the join using ANSI syntax you should make it an `INNER JOIN` to preserve the behavior of the original query.

Comment: my mistake on the inner... i was typing too fast, yes it should contain the inner syntax.

Comment: since 5.0 mysql actually caches views correctly.  so that when your querying against the table you don't have to order it anymore the view is stored as a cached table already ordered.  The first time the view is used its put into that state so that following calls will use the already cached table representation of the joined tables that haev already been ordered.

Comment: According to the documentation, in MySQL `Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set.`. What makes you think they are cached?

Comment: When I query against the view, I am still sitting at around 3 seconds... SELECT ID FROM  `vw_sorted_items` LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTIMIZE (SELECT DISTINCT item.ID, item.CREATED_AT
FROM  `item` ,  `image` 
WHERE item.COLLECTION_ID =9
AND item.REJECTED IS NULL 
AND image.ITEM_ID = item.ID
ORDER BY item.CREATED_AT DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30) WHILE (T < 3)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I don't think that's valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: Pretty sure it works in Btrieve, I thought it would transfer to MySql... my bad

Answer (score 0):

Some tips that might be useful :
1. Change index `item_FI_1` (`collection_id`) - add `REJECTED` to this index. I think you don't need an index `rejected` (`rejected`) at all - it seems to be not selective enough to be used at all.  For testing you can just create a new index on `collection_id, rejected` and see if it makes any difference.
2. Try a bit different query :

```
SELECT  i.ID, i.CREATED_AT
FROM  `item` i  
WHERE i.COLLECTION_ID =9
AND i.REJECTED IS NULL 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `image` im WHERE im.ITEM_ID = i.ID)
ORDER BY item.CREATED_AT DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Thanks, but after a little testing, I'm still at the same speeds.  It's the ORDER BY clause that's slowing me down, but it is very necessary.  Ugh.

Comment: Also, you might try adding `CREATED_AT` to the index `item_FI_1` - (`collection_id, created_at`)